# React Router 1.0 How to redirect write redirect code inside flux action

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can i redirect to dashboard from LoginAction? I am using React-router 1.0.

```
var Dispatcher = require('../dispatcher/appDispatcher');
var LoginConstants = require('../constants/LoginConstants');

var LoginActions ={
    LoginUser: function(data){
        localStorage.myapptoken= JSON.stringify(data);
        if(data.value != undefined)
        {
            //TODO: Navigate to dashboard.
        }
        Dispatcher.dispatch({
            actionType: LoginConstants.AUTHENTICATE_USER,
            authResponse: data
        });
    }
};

module.exports = LoginActions;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history)?

```
var history = require('history')
...
history.replaceState(null, '/dashboard')
```

From [Navigating Outside of Components](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md)

Note as the doc says you should init the history object yourself:

```
var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory')
...
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>{routes}</Router>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! the link Navigating Outside of Components worked for me.